# Did the European Commission officially mention that pensions should obey some sort of contribution-related principle?

Tags: pensions, european-commission

#### Context

I have watched an interview with a financial expert arguing about the big impact of so-called "special pensions" in Romania (1-2% of GDP). This is confirmed by some politicians that argued about [pensions that might be bigger than the salary](https://www.digi24.ro/stiri/actualitate/politica/kelemen-hunor-pensia-ar-trebui-sa-fie-cel-mult-75-din-salariul-net-sunt-pensii-mai-mari-decat-salariul-brut-si-nu-e-corect-1565337).

The same person argued that the European Commission considers "special" pensions the ones not obeying some sort of contribution-related principle (i.e. there is a proportionality between contributions to the pension fund during the active professional life and the pension amount). As a consequence having "special" pensions is something that should be avoided.

#### Research

I have tried finding an official text related to those above and found [this article](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/HTML/?uri=CELEX:52012DC0037&from=EN), but I am not sure the "special" pensions topic is touched in any way. What seems to be related to the contribution related principle:

> The PSEO follows the actuarial balance principle. The annual
> contribution paid by the staff has to cover one third of the rights
> that the staff have acquired during a given year. The acquired rights
> of EU civil servants during that given year correspond to the future
> pensions that the staff will receive after retirement, as well as to
> the entitlement (under certain conditions) to an invalidity allowance,
> a survivor's pension, and an orphan's pension. In other words, the
> annual contribution is designed to finance one third of the service
> cost under the pension scheme, i.e. a series of payments that will
> arise in the future. In order to make this computation possible, the
> series of payments for European civil servants has to be evaluated at
> its present value (using an interest rate "discount rate"). The
> computation is thus an actuarial valuation.

**Question:** Did the European Commission officially mention that pensions should obey some sort of contribution-related  principle?

Comment: Meh. I feel this a question with an easy escape hatch. Even if they did, what's to stop "special" pensions from being the result of larger (as a percentage) "special" contributions that are part of the pay package?

Comment: FWTW, MEP pensions are based on years of service. 3.5% per year, capped at 70%, i.e. 20 years. https://www.europarl.europa.eu/news/en/faq/13/salaries-and-pensions

Comment: Germany has a system where 'traditional-style' civil service pensions (for *Beamte*) are not matched by contributions out of the salary. This has been going on for centuries and it is understood by (almost) all -- with a civil serivce job, the relation of nominal and actual income and retirement pay is different than for other jobs, and any job-seeker will factor that into their decisions. In recent decades more civil-service positions use the normal pension schemes (for *Angestellte* im öffentlichen Dienst).

Comment: (contd.) There are a few cases where the pension can match the final salary, e.g. for a professor emeritus.